# Wordpress child theme - Overriding a php file which is not in the root folder of a theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to modify a php file which is in "/inc/sections" folder of the Shop Isle theme (Wordpress) through a child theme. I tried the classic way by creating a new php file with the same name in my child theme but it s not working. I ve read there is a way to make the child file overriding the parent one using a function.

All what I ve tried didn t work or like this code below create some bugs (scrolling problem, blank space, etc):

```
<?php
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/sections/shop_isle_big_title_section.php' ;
?>
```

Do you know a solution ?

---

front-page.php code:

```
/* Wrapper start */

echo '<div class="main">';
$big_title = get_template_directory() . '/inc/sections/shop_isle_big_title_section.php';
load_template( apply_filters( 'shop-isle-subheader', $big_title ) );
```

Comment: you'll need to look through the theme and see in which template they include the file, and override that too, for example if `/inc/sections/shop_isle_big_title_section.php` is included in `home.php` then you have to override that and include your modified version

Comment: Like @andrew said, you'll have to override the way the script has been integrated with the theme. I had the same issue with the Flatsome theme. Unfortunately there are no options than doing this the ugly way, by finding where the script has been linked, and therefore overriding it. Bare in mind at the moment you override the inc/ folder you will probably not be able to update it anymore..

Comment: Thanks for helping. Ok I think I found what you say Andrew in the front-page.php file. I ll try to do something and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok it s working now!!!

I just had to create a new front-page.php in my child theme and replace "template" of get_template_directory with "stylesheet" ...

Thanks for your help