# Wordpress child theme - Shopisle changing big title

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114155/wordpress-child-theme-overriding-a-php-file-which-is-not-in-the-root-folder-of) which describes exactly my problem but I tried the solution and it doesn't work.

Here is my front-page.php code:

```
<?php
get_header();
/* Wrapper start */

echo '<div class="main">';
$big_title = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/shop_isle_big_title_section.php';
load_template( apply_filters( 'shop-isle-subheader', $big_title ) );
```

And here my shop_isle_big_title_section.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Big title section
 *
 * @package ShopIsle
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

$shop_isle_homepage_slider_shortcode = get_theme_mod( 'shop_isle_homepage_slider_shortcode' );
$shop_isle_big_title_hide            = get_theme_mod( 'shop_isle_big_title_hide' );

if ( isset( $shop_isle_big_title_hide ) && $shop_isle_big_title_hide != 1 ) {
    echo '<section id="home" class="home-section home-parallax home-fade' . ( empty( $shop_isle_homepage_slider_shortcode ) ? ' home-full-height' : ' home-slider-plugin' ) . '">';
} elseif ( is_customize_preview() ) {
    echo '<section id="home" class="home-section home-parallax home-fade shop_isle_hidden_if_not_customizer' . ( empty( $shop_isle_homepage_slider_shortcode ) ? ' home-full-height' : ' home-slider-plugin' ) . '">';
}

    if ( ! empty( $shop_isle_homepage_slider_shortcode ) ) {
        echo do_shortcode( $shop_isle_homepage_slider_shortcode );
    } else {

        $shop_isle_big_title_image    = get_theme_mod( 'shop_isle_big_title_image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/background-video.jpg' );
        $shop_isle_big_title_title    = get_theme_mod( 'shop_isle_big_title_title', 'Test' );
        $shop_isle_big_title_subtitle = get_theme_mod( 'shop_isle_big_title_subtitle', __( 'WooCommerce Theme', 'shop-isle' ) );

        if ( ! empty( $shop_isle_big_title_image ) ) {

            echo '<div class="hero-slider">';

            echo '<ul class="slides">';

            //echo '<li class="bg-dark" style="background-image:url(' . esc_url( $shop_isle_big_title_image ) . ')">';

            echo '<div class="home-slider-overlay"></div>';
            echo '<div class="hs-caption">';
            echo '<div class="caption-content">';

            if ( ! empty( $shop_isle_big_title_title ) ) {
                echo '<h1 class="hs-title-size-4 font-alt mb-30">Test Custom</h1>';
            } elseif ( is_customize_preview() ) {
                echo '<h1 class="hs-title-size-4 font-alt mb-30"></h1>';
            }

            if ( ! empty( $shop_isle_big_title_subtitle ) ) {
                echo '<div class="hs-title-size-1 font-alt mb-40">Custom Sub</div>';
            } elseif ( is_customize_preview() ) {
                echo '<div class="hs-title-size-1 font-alt mb-40"></div>';
            }

            shop_isle_big_title_section_display_button();
            echo '</div><!-- .caption-content -->';
            echo '</div><!-- .hs-caption -->';

            echo '</li><!-- .bg-dark -->';

            echo '</ul><!-- .slides -->';

            echo '</div><!-- .hero-slider -->';

        }
    }// End if().

echo '</section >';
```

As you can see the big title should normally display the text "Test Custom" and "Custom sub" and with no background, which it doesn't. I hope someone can see what I did wrong. What I want is that my changes are showed, which it does not in this case (yes my child theme is working correctly).

Comment: what do you want to display on page? Please explain in details.

Comment: @PriyankaModi my goal is to display [particle js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) but that's not a problem, the problem is that my changes doesn't happen

Comment: that's mean you can try to use this code in your project. right?

Comment: @PriyankaModi Yes i can try to use the code, but the problem is that whatever I changed or add, it won't show